# Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/digit/form/FORM].js”

Tags: dojo, syntax-error

/* Below is my code I am trying to add button using using require in the digit form in the code but it shows loading failed for script.I am just using basic syntax but I dont know what exactly is wrong can anybody tell please*/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Intro to Dojo, part 1 </title>
        <style>
            .highlight {
                 background: yellow;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body> 
    <ul id="nav">
        <li> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="highlight"> <a href="/portfolio"> Portfolio </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/about">Abou</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <p> This is a paragraph (albeit a very <em>short</em> paragraph). Also, <a href="http://google.com">here&#39;s a link</a>. </p>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script>dojo.create("p", { innerHTML: "Hi there!"}, dojo.body(), "first");

        dojo.create("h1", { innerHTML: "Heading"}, dojo.query("p")[0], "after");
        var h = dojo.query("p")[0],

            handle = dojo.connect(h, "onclick", function () {
                alert("learning Dojo");
                dojo.disconnect(handle);
            });

        var items = dojo.query("li");

        items.attr("innerHTML"); // [" <a href="/">Home</a>", " <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>", " <a href="/about">About</a>", " <a href="/contact">Contact</a>"]

        items.attr({ className: "btn" });

        require(["digit/form/FORM]"],function(){
        var btn = new dijit.form.Button({ label: "Hello" });  
        dojo.place(btn.domNode, dojo.body());
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mispelled library name passed to `require`. Firstly there is typo with right square bracket in `digit/form/FORM]`. Moreover there is no module named `FORM` in dojo toolkit and dojo widgets library is called `dijit`, not a `digit`.  Finally you are about to create button of dijit library so in fact you probably wanted to import `dijit/form/Button`. That would lead to something like this:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button"], function (Button) {
    var btn = new Button({
        label: "Hello"
    });
    dojo.place(btn.domNode, dojo.body());
});
```